# Why does my interceptor that is defined on two modules get run twice?

Tags: angularjs

Why does `here` get logged out twice?

How can I avoid it from being logged out twice, while still using the `factory` module? (I want it because it makes testing easier)

Code:

```
angular
  .module('app', ['factory'])
  .controller('MainController', MainController)
  .factory('httpInterceptorFactory', httpInterceptorFactory)
  .config(config)
;

angular
  .module('factory', [])
  .factory('Factory', Factory)
  .factory('httpInterceptorFactory', httpInterceptorFactory)
  .config(config)
;

function MainController(Factory) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.sendRequest = function() {
    Factory.sendRequest();
  };
}

function Factory($http) {
  return {
    sendRequest: function() {
      $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    }
  };
}

function httpInterceptorFactory() {
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      console.log('here');
      return config;
    }
  };
}

function config($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptorFactory');
}
```

plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/9NMPVB2jvneud9KLfmQ4?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are including the same `config` twice so each will push the same interceptor to the interceptors array and therefore fire 2 instances per request.

Keep in mind that components are available throughout the app regardless of which module they are declared in.

So including your factory once will make it available anywhere

EDIT: After re-reading it appears you want to be able to include in both modules for testing.

If you want both config you could test if the interceptor is already in the array before pushing a duplicate.

```
function config($httpProvider) {
   if($httpProvider.interceptors.indexOf('httpInterceptorFactory') ===-1){
       $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptorFactory');
  }
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/7TcMYPR1coPypUac7B4U?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: So `$httpProvider` is shared amongst different modules? Could you explain a bit how that works?

Comment: Modules aren't isolated inside app. So the core providers only exist once per app, not per module

Comment: Thanks! If you wouldn't mind, I'd appreciate it if you could link me to a resource describing that and/or explaining further how "core providers work".

Comment: not sure exactly what you are asking but it is all in the docs. Also `core providers` are no different than other providers that you can create with respect to them only existing once in app

Comment: I was trying to ask "how could they exist once per app?" and "how could they exist if they're not on a module?". I just found the answer though. Under the hood, it seems that there's a core module called [ng](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng) that has all of these core providers, and presumably loads the other modules you declare as dependencies.

Comment: there's a whole section in docs about dependency injection also